# Unable to locate package mingw32

Tags: mingw32

A project I'm trying to compile needs mingw32. `apt-get install` gives me `Unable to locate package mingw32`.

Doing an `apt cache search` yields many options and I need help choosing one that will work or eliminate this error.

**System info:**

```
4.2.0-16-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 8 15:35:06 UTC 2015
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

This package is in universe repository of Ubuntu. So make sure you have enabled universe in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

To install it use the command:

```
sudo apt-get install mingw32
```

It will install packages `mingw32` `mingw32-binutils`  `mingw32-runtime` automatically

and

```
sudo apt-cache search mingw32

mingw32 - Minimalist GNU win32 (cross) compiler
mingw32-binutils - Minimalist GNU win32 (cross) binutils
mingw32-runtime - Minimalist GNU win32 (cross) runtime
```

no need to select one. These packages are dependency of `mingw32`

**Note :** Currently these packages are available in `trusty`, `utopic` and earlier version of Ubuntu. If you are using the latest Ubuntu version then check [Ubuntu package search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&arch=i386&searchon=names&keywords=mingw32) if package available or not. If not then either download package and install manually or download source and compile it.

**EDIT:**
You can also try this:

For 32bit system:

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mingw32/mingw32_4.2.1.dfsg-2ubuntu1_i386.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mingw32-binutils/mingw32-binutils_2.20-0.2ubuntu1_i386.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mingw32-runtime/mingw32-runtime_3.15.2-0ubuntu1_all.deb
```

For 64bit system

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mingw32/mingw32_4.2.1.dfsg-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mingw32-binutils/mingw32-binutils_2.20-0.2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mingw32-runtime/mingw32-runtime_3.15.2-0ubuntu1_all.deb
```

Install these packages using the command:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

If it shows dependencies then use command :

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

and again install

```
 sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Comment: I'm running wily & yes universe is enabled

Comment: try updated answer .

Comment: changing the OS to ubuntu-14.04-lamp_64bit seems to have solved all my  problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I met such an issue from a command from a chip vendor:

```
sudo apt-get install gawk git gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential \
zip curl libc6-dev libncurses5-dev:i386 x11proto-core-dev \
libx11-dev:i386 libreadline6-dev:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 \
libgl1-mesa-dev g++-multilib mingw32 tofrodos \
python-markdown libxml2-utils xsltproc zlib1g-dev:i386
```

I am working on a 64-bit platform, so I changed **mingw32** to **mingw-w64** and it passed.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60387020/unable-to-locate-package-any-package-mingw32-mingw64-curses-on-ubuntu-18-04/60389640#60389640

The package name you're using is incorrect.
go to this link and check the for the correct package name.
https://packages.ubuntu.com/

Or see the above mentioned linked you'll see all the steps to follow.

I hope this will help.